# Is it possible that I add margin border line or frame on TCPDF?

Tags: php, tcpdf

Is there anyway that I can put frame of my pdf(tcpdf) ?

or just a simple border margin box like `border:2px solid black;` will do.

I just discover tcpdf and I check their example and I can't find about frame.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for can be controlled with:

[`Rect()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a8fc7b86c255aeb0f14d281bdaeb2015c)

TCPDF shows an example called [graphic methods (PHP)](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_012.phps) ([PDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_012.pdf)).

Also, you can look at:

[`SetMargin`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#ab3bbdb7c85ea08d175fd559be6132ba0)

It can take a bit of setup but works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this method: [PDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_035.pdf), [PHP](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_035.phps), which uses `SetLineStyle()`.